# how to read GPS information on linux and on windows

Tags: gps

Is it possible to get location information from the GPS to my laptop?
As I understand it, I can connect the GPS device by a cable to my laptop (through UART or through USB) and get this information.

I don't have a specific GPS device, so any example of how to get this information on any device will be great.

(My main goal is to save this information on a file while I'm driving and then, by using an online map, see the places I've beem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have a UART / RS232 type connection, GPS is typically streamed through in [NMEA 0183](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_0183) format which is comma separated ASCII.  It is easy enough to decode, and there are plenty of [free examples](http://www.google.ie/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&gs_nf=1&cp=23&gs_id=9&xhr=t&q=C%2b%2b%20NMEA%20parser%20example&pf=p&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=C%2b%2b%20NMEA%20parser%20example&aq=0&aqi=g1&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=cca1ae598fc41ffc&biw=1280&bih=899&ion=1) out there on how to do this.

Comment: Any GPS systems that I've worked with that have serial output have options to stream NMEA 0183 as it is the longest established standard.  The problem can be that low end receivers simply don't have any serial output.  You also see bluetooth commonly used in place of RS232 these days, but this often still ends up as NMEA over a virtual COM port.  Which devices are you targetting?

Comment: Hi Shane, I couldn't find what I'm looking for. What I need is a c code that parses the GPS sentences, and puts the information in some kind of data structure. I couldn't find a free c code that does that. ( I don't care about the GUI representation)